# how to stop event keydown listener temporary?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, animation, 2d-games

my Problem is:after the new circle created, it still animating fast(decreasing variable animation did not helped)-> how to kill the keydown event listener temporary after collision is happened so that the speed of new circle can not be effected by the spacebar of the first session?

I am trying to make simple game2d using canvas and javascript.

the circle should be moving faster since the spacebar key is pressed(increasing variable of animation function ).
but if there is collision with the wall it should be gameover then new circle should be created. this is happening actually right now.

```
move(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 65 ) { //left
    this.cir.x -= 1 
  } else if (event.keyCode === 68 ) { //right
    this.cir.x += 1
  } else if (event.keyCode === 83 ) { //down
    if(cir.coll){
      this.cir = new cir(1,0);
    } 
    this.cir.x+= 1
  } else if (event.key == ' ' ) { // spacebar button
    this.dropInterval = 1 
    if(cir.coll){
      this.cir = new cir(1,0) **// for new circle spacebar keydown should be killed temporary so that i should press it again for the new object**
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a global boolean variable **deactivated** which you check before executing the code that should run if the spacebar is pressed. If a new circle is created, set it to **true**. To reset this variable you can add a **keyUp** event listener which fires as soon as a key is released - the spacebar in your case.

e.g.

```
var deactivated = false;

window.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.key == " ") {
    deactivated = false;
  }
});

function move(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 65) { //left
    this.cir.x -= 1
  } else if (event.keyCode === 68) { //right
    this.cir.x += 1
  } else if (event.keyCode === 83) { //down
    if (cir.coll) {
      this.cir = new cir(1, 0);
    }
    this.cir.x += 1
  } else if (event.key == ' ' && !deactivated) { // spacebar button
    this.dropInterval = 1
    if (cir.coll) {
      this.cir = new cir(1, 0);
      deactivated = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what i need is forcing the player to click the spacebar button again after the new cir is created.

Comment: I refined my anwer!

Answer (score 0):

If you want only to stop the spacebar keydown event from firing, you could try to create a boolean value like "canPressSpace" and when the circle collides with the wall you call a function to set this boolean to false for a limited time or until some other event triggers it back on.

On the spacebar keydown event, just add an `if (canPressSpace)` verification.

I'm not sure if this will solve your animation problem but it should temporarily stop the spacebar keydown event functionality.